# WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Governance registry integration

Tags: wso2

Following
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+Separate+Nodes

i tried to integrated WSO2 API manager with Governance registry.

I am running both of them with different offsets.

After login to API Manager Mgtm Console i get errors while accessing different links 'OAuth' 'Service Bus - APIs' etc.

1. Error occurred while reading OAuth application data
2. The following error details are available. Please refer logs for more details.
   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to get server context
3. Error while loading authorized applications
4. error
   The following error details are available. Please refer logs for more details.
   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) local://services/FlowsAdminService

Answer (score 0):

Seems some thing missing in document.

I was able to resolve this issue by updating the domain thing based on the product and did not kept it wso2.carbon.domain as is by default. For e.g

```
<parameter name="domain">wso2.esb.domain</parameter>
```

this solved my problem and i am running all WSO2 products this way.